# Do I need MySQL installed locally as well?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 ubuntu 11.04 servers on IPs 192.168.9.14 and 192.168.9.15.  On .14 I have installed ruby + rails and on .15 I have installed mysql and the database for my site resides on .15

I now want to get rails 2.3.8 to connect from .14 to the database on .15.  I have the following in my database.yml on .14.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gtt_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: admin
  host: 192.168.9.15
  port: 3306
```

I'm currently getting an error showing up in my rails log as follows:

Can't connect to MySQL server on 192.168.9.15.

I originally thought this was due to user privileges on the mysql server but I have now added that in and still getting the same problem.

So I then tried connecting via a terminal (command line) as follows:

```
mysql -h 192.168.9.15 -uroot -p
```

and I got a message saying :

```
The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
   * mysql-client-cor-5.1
 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

...And that's what makes me think I need a local copy of mysql even though the database completely resides on another server.

Please can someone confirm whether my 'guess' is correct or whether there is some 'clever' way of connecting to the mysql server on .15 without also installing mysql on .14.

Comment: you would only need to install the mysql client in order to run the `mysql` command from the console. You should know though that what you need to install in order to run the mysql client from the command line is completely separate from what you need to have for Rails to connect ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the client - `sudo apt-get install mysql` The server is usually `mysql-server`

Did you install the mysql gem for ruby? Rails will need this in order to connect to the DB. Also make sure .15 can accept remote requests from .14.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried doing a sudo apt-get install mysql and I got back saying 'Unable to locate package mysql'.  When I installed mysql on .15 I had done the following:  sudo apt-get install mysql-server libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev.  I'm wondering whether I should do the last 2 in this case.  Would you or any one else know?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-cor-5.1` (I'm not sure which version you've installed, the numbers make a difference eg. 50 vs 51 vs 55). Also, did you install the gem? `gem list` and see if mysql is there. If not, run `sudo gem install mysql`

Comment: OK this is a PAIN. I would like to accept BOTH answers (yours and luckytaxis) as you both provided part of the answer. I had to change my.cnf to bind correctly to 192.168.9.14 AND I had to install the mysql client. The command for which is apt-get install mysql-client.

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured your mysql db to listen to external IP traffic? I dont think MySQL by default allows external connections, only localhost traffic. Check your my.cnf.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have another configuration of 2 servers set up like the ones I mentioned EXCEPT that the server that I'm trying to connect from also has mysql (server) installed already and the my.cnf file only shows a bind = 127.0.0.1.  So I'm guessing that is not the answer here.  I'll confirm this later once I've tried luckytaxi's suggestion.

Comment: OK this is a PAIN.  I would like to accept BOTH answers (yours and luckytaxis) as you both provided part of the answer.  I had to change my.cnf to bind correctly to 192.168.9.14 AND I had to install the mysql client.  The command for which is apt-get install mysql-client

Comment: No problem with me, mate. Your problem is solved, that whats important :)